# Bounds on spectral norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, upper-lower-bounds

I am reading about the connection between spectral norm and spectral radius and more particularly about

> **Lemma**: let $A\in M_n$ and $\epsilon>0$ be given. There is a matrix norm $||\cdot||$ such that $\rho(A) \leq ||A|| \leq \rho(A) + \epsilon$
>
> > Proof: For unitary $U$ and upper triangular $N$ we have $A=UNU^{H}$. Set $D_t = diag(t, t^2, \dots,t^n)$ and compute
> > $$D_tND_t^{-1}=\left[
> >     \begin{array}{ccccc}
> >       \lambda_1& t^{-1}N_{12} & t^{-2}N_{13} & \dots & t^{-n+1}N_{1n} \\
> >       & \lambda_2 & t^{-1}N_{23} & \dots &t^{-n+2}N_{2n} \\
> >       &               & \lambda_3                \\
> >       & \text{0}      &         & \ddots & t^{-1}N_{n-1,n}            \\
> >       &               &         &     &  \lambda_n
> >     \end{array}
> >     \right].$$ Thus, for $t>0$ large enough, the sum of all the absolute values of the off-diagonal entries of $D_tND_t^{-1}$ is less than $\epsilon$. In particular, $||D_tND_t^{-1}||_1 \leq \rho(A)+\epsilon$ for all large enough $t$. Thus, if we define the matrix norm $||\cdot||$ by $||B||=||D_tU^HBUD_t^{-1}||_1=||B||=||(D_tU^H)B(D_t^{-1}U^H)^{-1}||_1$ and replace $B$ with $A=UNU^{H}$ we conclude that
> > $$||A|| \leq \rho(A) + \epsilon$$ for sufficiently large $\epsilon$.

My questions are

1. Why the author states that the absolute values of the off-diagonal entries of $D_tND_t^{-1}$ is less than $\epsilon$ and thus $||D_tND_t^{-1}||_1 \leq \rho(A)+\epsilon$? Can we show that more analyticaly?
2. Can we define $$||A||^t \leq (\rho(A) + \epsilon_t)^t$$ with $\lim_{t \to\infty}\epsilon_t=0$, i.e., with a diminishing sequence $\epsilon_t$? If the aforementioned inequality is defined should we have $\rho(A) + \epsilon_t < 1$?

*EDIT:* $N_{ij}$ was previously $d_{ij}$ I changed it to make more clear the multiplication. So in comments consider $d_{ij}=N_{ij}$.

Comment: (1) $D_tND_t^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix plus a matrix with entries bounded in absolute value by  $t^{-1}M$ for some $M$. This can be estimated above in $L^1$-norm by $t^{-1}$ times the sum of the individual matrices $ME_{ij}$ with corresponding elementary matrices. We obtain an explicit bound times $t^{-1}$. (2) The "definition" also depends on the unitary $U$.

Comment: @dan_fulea Thanks for he interest. Why they are bounded in absolute value by $t^{-1}M$? Is it possible to provide more details?

Comment: Take $M$ to be the maximum over all $|d_{ij}|$. (Of course, $M\ge 0$ depends on the choices of $U$ and $N$ in the decomposition of $A$.) Then consider only $t$-values with $t>1$.